# Update a row using idiorm and php

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

I have this function to update a record, but i cannot it fails and send me a "Primary key ID missing from row or is null" message, how can I fix it?

```
public static function update_child($data)
{
    try
    {
        $update= ORM::for_table("dm_child",DM_TAG)
                        ->where_equal($data["id_child"]);

        $update -> set(array(
            "gender" => $data["gender"]
            "age_year" =>$data["year"]
            "age_month" => $data["month"]

        ));
        $update -> save();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        ORM::get_db()->rollBack();
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Idiorm assumes that the name of the primary key is 'id', which is not that, in your case.
Therefore you have to explicitly specify it to Idiorm:

```
<?php
    ORM::configure('id_column_overrides', array(
    'dm_child' => 'id_child',
    'other_table' => 'id_table',
));
```

See [Docs>Configuration](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#id1).

Comment: yes, this might also be the reason, and if you're using idiorm remember to do this if you're primary id name is not 'id'!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed the one provided by @iNpwd for changing the default 'id' column name for queries on a per table basis:

```
ORM::configure('id_column_overrides', array(
    'table_name'  => 'column_name_used_as_id',
    'other_table' => array('pk_1', 'pk_2') // a compound primary key
));
```

The thing that was biting me on getting it to recognize my query was WHERE I was changing the `ORM::configure` values. I was not in the correct file.

A deeper link to specifically the ID Column configuration: http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#id-column

Comment: This is beautiful answered thank a lot, for all the tables configuration

Answer (score 1):

I just met this problem 2 minutes ago. The real reason is, you forgot select id field in querying.
demo:

```
$demo = ORM::for_table('demo')->select('field_test')->find_one($id);
$demo->field_test = 'do';
$demo->save();
```

You will get the error.
change to :

```
$demo = ORM::for_table('demo')->select('field_test')->select('id')->find_one($id);
```

It will fix the problem.

Some tips in documents:
https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/test/ORMTest.php

/**
     * These next two tests are needed because if you have select()ed some fields,
     * but not the primary key, then the primary key is not available for the
     * update/delete query - see issue #203.
     * We need to change the primary key here to something other than `id`
     * becuase MockPDOStatement->fetch() always returns an id.
     */

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, nor should it. Their own documentation doesn't show it required: http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#updating-records

Answer (score 0):

I've never used idiorm, so cannot guarantee that my answer will work for you, but from this [page](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html) and under "Updating records", we have an example which is similar but slightly different to yours.

```
// The 5 means the value of 5 in the primary-key column
$person = ORM::for_table('person')->find_one(5);

// The following two forms are equivalent
$person->set('name', 'Bob Smith');
$person->age = 20;

// This is equivalent to the above two assignments
$person->set(array(
    'name' => 'Bob Smith',
    'age'  => 20
));

// Syncronise the object with the database
$person->save();
```

Comment: I also tried this example, but I've got same result  :/

Comment: Also running into this issue.

Comment: Have you set a primary-key column? I personally do all of my SQL statements by hand (ie, "UPDATE table SET column_1 = '$value_safe'!") where $value_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($value). Anyway, I'm distracting you with what might not be relevant to you, but little things like not setting a primary key, adding a repeat value to a unique field, etc, are often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I'll learn the reason behind this, but let me tell you all I understand at the moment, and how I "fixed" it.

Here is the beginning of [idiorm's save function](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/blob/master/idiorm.php#L1982-L1994):

```php
public function save() {
    $query = array();
    // remove any expression fields as they are already baked into the query
    $values = array_values(array_diff_key($this->_dirty_fields, $this->_expr_fields));
    if (!$this->_is_new) { // UPDATE
        // If there are no dirty values, do nothing
        if (empty($values) && empty($this->_expr_fields)) {
            return true;
        }
        $query = $this->_build_update();
        $id = $this->id(true);
```

Right there, on that last line, when trying to access the **$this->id**, you are getting an exception thrown:

```
throw new Exception('Primary key ID missing from row or is null');
```

**$this** does not contain an id property. I'm not really sure how it could. The example given both [on their homepage](http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/) and [in the docs](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#updating-records) doesn't do anything special to address this. In fact I am copying them 1:1 and still yielding the same error as you.

So, all that said, I fixed this error by just adding in my own id:

```
$crop = ORM::for_table('SCS_Crop')->find_one($id);
$crop->id = $id;
$crop->Name = "Foo";
$crop->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when the **id** field name is ambiguous, e.g. when joining two tables both having an id column. This is the case with referenced tables

```
Model::factory('tableOne')
->left_outer_join('tableTwo', array('tableOne.tableTwo_id', '=', 'tableTwo.id'))
->find_one($id);
```

In these cases set an **alias** to the ID column of the parent *tableOne* to later access it while saving. Make sure that you also select other columns you need - e.g. by ->select('*'):

```
Model::factory('tableOne')
->select('*')
->select('tableOne.id', 'id')
->left_outer_join('tableTwo', array('tableOne.tableTwo_id', '=', 'tableTwo.id'))
->find_one($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

if in table primary key/ field name not id  then following id column overrides required
default id (primary_key) to replace with other id name (primary_key)

```
    ORM::configure('id_column_overrides', array(
        'user'  => 'user_id',
    ));

    $update = ORM::for_table('user')->find_one(1);
    $update->name = "dev";
    try{
        $update->save();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

    print_r($update);
```